# ArrayList, List

Tags: java, algorithm

When i am trying to solve subset problem, I write a code like that:

```
    public class Subsets {
        public List<List<Integer>> subsets(int[] nums) {
            List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
            Arrays.sort(nums);
            backtrack(list, new ArrayList<>(), nums, 0);
            return list;
        }
        public void backtrack(List<List<Integer>> list, ArrayList<Integer>temp, int[] nums, int start){
            list.add(temp);
            for(int i = start; i<nums.length;i++){
                temp.add(nums[i]);
                backtrack(list, temp, nums, i++);
                temp.remove(temp.size()-1);
            }        
        }
    }
```

The output is

> [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]

but the correct answer should be

> [[3],[1],[2],[1,2,3],[1,3],[2,3],[1,2],[]]

When I change the "backtrack" code like that, the answer is correct:

```
public void backtrack(List<List<Integer>> list, List<Integer> temp, int[] nums, int start){
  list.add(new ArrayList(temp));
  for(int i = start; i<nums.length;i++){
   temp.add(nums[i]);
   backtrack(list, temp, nums, i+1);
   temp.remove(temp.size()-1);
   }
 }
```

My question: why do I need to write code like that:

```
    public void backtrack(List<List<Integer>> list, List<Integer> temp, int[] nums, int start){
        list.add(new ArrayList(temp));
```

instead of that:

```
    public void backtrack(List<List<Integer>> list, ArrayList<Integer> temp, int[] nums, int start){
        list.add(temp);
```

Comment: Thanks for the really quick accept. I am glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
list.add(new ArrayList(temp));
```

that creates a **new** List object, with the content of `temp` at **this** point of time.

Whereas

```
list.add(temp);
```

just adds a reference to the existing `temp` List to `list`.

So, in the second case, when you **later** modify `temp` that also affects the content of `list`.

But beyond that: you code is much harder to read/understand as it ought to be. There is **no** point in using a `temp` parameter to that method. You could make `temp` a local variable inside the method for example. The incoming list is **empty** anyway. You don't gain anything from making this an input parameter; you only add confusion.

And then you improve your naming - as `list` or `temp` really doesn't speak to the reader what the *intend usages* of these variables is.

Answer (score 0):

`list.add(temp)` will add reference to the same `temp` object to the list. Later on, you remove elements from it until it's empty, and the algorithm ends with a list containing several references to the same empty list.

Using `new ArrayList(temp)` (or better yet - the type-safe `new ArrayList<>(temp)`) will create a new list with the same content as `temp`, so later on, when you remove elements from `temp`, this list is not affected.